# Electronics to Measure Impact / Pressure

Tags: usb, design

I am looking to setup device(s) that measures levels of impact / pressure and which then can be transferred via cable back to a computer for analysis. Ideally I want to buy a premade solution that is modifiable and can handle input from more than one device.

Can anyone suggest something like this or what a certain type of electronic may be called?

Ideally the electronics should be small, no larger than a thumb size. Realistically I know this chance is small, but free software to go with the paid devices would be a bonus.

Any ideas welcome

Thanks

Comment: Look into pressure sensors made by Tekscan:  http://www.tekscan.com/products

Comment: Knowing the desired range of magnitudes of impacts/pressures/forces/torques/precessions/twists/bumps in the night would be of immense value in providing a well fitted answer. And how mayn points do you want to telemeter. And how often do you want to be able to measure. And how long do the forces hand about or last. Best of all, telling us what you WANT would help immensely. Then we can assist with what you need. Present query has a layer of obscuration which makes elicitation problematic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for a ready-made product it's asking for shopping advice and that's off-topic. We like to *make* things.

What you're looking for is a **force sensor**; pressure sensors are for gases and fluids. You don't say what force range you need to detect, but [this one](http://www.meas-spec.com/product/t_product.aspx?id=2442) senses compression forces from 750 to 1500 grams force.

[image]

For industrial premade solutions that can handle input from more than 1 device a **PLC** will be able to handle that.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment. Do you know if it's possible to get these in a form of strip? Something that you could ideally coat an entire surface with

Comment: @supergeek1982 - Ah, from your description ("thumb size") I thought you wanted something button-like. Strips exist, they're usually referred to as FSR (Force Sensing Resistor) strips. [Here](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/24-inch-force-sensing-resistor.aspx)'s an example.